# Stuck doing migration using SSH in git for Fortrabbit

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, fortrabbit

I'm stuck trying to do a migration on fortrabbit. I'm up to the part in git where  you put this line in for `"ssh u-my-app@ssh1.eu1.frbit.com"` so I added it - I tried the name of my app `"ssh u-advkit@ssh1.eu1.frbit.com"` and I get permission denied public key. I got no email with the contents for this part and I've been following this tutorial and it's at the end of it in the last 2-3 minutes can some one help please

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rblX6Ta1-U

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect with `SSH` ? make sure the server allowed SSH access to it, and the port are open (default is 22).

For connecting to server with SSH, if you're on Linux by default `SSH` client will be available on Windows you need `PUTTY` for doing that.

Usage is as follows

```
ssh username@hostname -p portnumber
```

eg: `ssh phpadmin@myhost.com -p 22` (if the port is 22 no need to mention that).

While you connect it will ask for the password , Once the password entered first time it will store the public key on your machine , you just need to type `Yes` in the CLI. Next time on words it just verify password only.

If you're getting permission error might be user don't have SSH access to the server

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Remarks**:
The linked video is 2 years old. The fortrabbit platform has evolved, most general concepts stay the same, but workflows have changed. Please refer to the [documentation](http://help.fortrabbit.com) for up-to-date tutorials.

Please also respect that StackOverflow is for general questions that might help other users. Your question is very specific > fortrabbit support. Please don't reveal personal informations like your App name here.

**Answer**:
The "permission denied" message can have multiple causes: Probably SSH is not enabled for 'Old Apps', 'New Apps' don't even have SSH access any more.